# $param name in div

Tags: xml, xslt

I have A $param that I am passing into a template. I wish to use the value of this parameter as class name for a div. The class is not taking the value of the parameter but taking the parameter name (in the html page it is $param). Is there any way I can use the value of a parameter as a class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<div>
<xsl:attribute name="class">
<xsl:value-of select="$param"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

To use a XSLT expression in an attribute of a literal result element, surround the expression with braces like so:

`<div class="{$param}"> ... </div>`

This is known as an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-attribute-value-template).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the xsl:attribute element to add the value , for example,

```
print("<div><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="$param" /></xsl:attribute></div>");
```